# jQuery carousel navigation breaking on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I made a post carousel, with the help of the code I got from SO, and it mostly works, but I have a problem with resizing the window.

The whole thing is here

https://github.com/dingo-d/Post-Excerpt-Carousel

It works fine if you reload it on a certain window width, but if you just resize the window, the navigation stops working as it should.

Right now, when you are at the first post, you cannot go to previous (carousel won't move), and when you're at the last, the carousel also won't move forward. But if you resize, they will. The jquery code that is making this work is this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $(window).on('load', function () {
        $('.post_excerpt_carousel').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            post_excerpt_positioning($this);
        });
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        $('.post_excerpt_carousel').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($(window).width()>760) {
                $(this).find('li').css('width', '570px');
            }
            post_excerpt_positioning($this);
        });
    });

    function post_excerpt_positioning(e){

        var $carousel = e;
        var outer_width = $(window).outerWidth();
        var container_width;

        if (outer_width > 1190) {
            container_width = 1170;
        }

        if (outer_width > 960 && outer_width < 1190) {
            container_width = 960;
        }

        if (outer_width < 960) {
            container_width = parseInt((9/10)*outer_width,10);
        }

        var $prev = $carousel.find('.carousel_prev');
        var $next = $carousel.find('.carousel_next');
        var duration = $carousel.data('duration');
        var li_number = $carousel.find('li').length;
        var $ul = $carousel.find('ul');
        var $li = $ul.find('li');

        if (outer_width < 760){
            $li.css('width', container_width);
            $li.eq(1).addClass('active');
            if ($li.eq(2).hasClass('active')) {
                $li.eq(2).removeClass('active');
            }
        } else if (outer_width > 760){
            $li.eq(1).addClass('active');
            $li.eq(2).addClass('active');
        }

        var list_width = $carousel.find('li').outerWidth(true);
        var left_offset;
        if ($('.boxed_body_wrapper').length) {
            left_offset = list_width-60;
        } else{
            left_offset = parseInt(list_width - (outer_width - container_width-42)/2, 10);
        }

        $ul.css({'display': 'inline-block', 'width': li_number * $carousel.find('li').outerWidth(true) + 'px', 'left': -left_offset + 'px'});


        var not_active_no = $carousel.find('li').not('.first').not('.last').not('.active').length;
        var not_active_width = not_active_no * $carousel.find('li').outerWidth(true);

        $carousel.on('click', '.carousel_next', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $li = $ul.find('li');
            var $a = $('.active', $carousel);

            if (!$a.next().hasClass('last') && !$ul.is(':animated')) {
                $a.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            }

            if (parseInt($ul.css('left'), 10) != -parseInt(not_active_width + left_offset, 10) && !$ul.is(':animated')) {
                $ul.animate({
                    left: parseInt($ul.css('left'), 10) - $ul.find('li').outerWidth(true),
                }, duration);
            }
        });

        $carousel.on('click', '.carousel_prev', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $li = $ul.find('li');
            var $a = $('.active', $carousel);

            if (!$a.prev().hasClass('first') && !$ul.is(':animated')) {
                $a.removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
            }

            if (parseInt($ul.css('left'), 10) !== -parseInt(left_offset, 10) && !$ul.is(':animated')) {
                $ul.animate({
                    left: parseInt($ul.css('left'), 10) + $ul.find('li').outerWidth(true),
                }, duration);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

The main issue is that when you resize you obviously change the offsets, and the animation happens. The second issue is that I have `on.('click')` events inside a function that I'm calling, and I don't think this is a correct way to code, so any help around this will help.

Codepen showcasing it is here: http://codepen.io/dingo_d/pen/doNyMw

Comment: One thing you may want to check is that you keep binding click events on window resize (in the `post_excerpt_positioning` function). I would remove any `click` events before you attach new ones. So instead of `$carousel.on('click' ...` I would do this: `$carousel.off('click').on('click' ...`

Comment: You mean to add the click events with your code in the resize function?

Comment: Yes, I would give it a shot. Just add the `.off('click')` before the `.on('click')`. This will detach any previous click events before it adds the new one. It may get rid of the odd behavior you are experiencing with your navigation arrows on window resizing

Comment: Tried it, didn't work, plus I had to add a bunch of code for the offsets to work. I cannot put the onclick events out of the function, because I need them to work for multiple carousels on the same page :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've ditched the function, because the function and the `on click` events delegation inside it were a bad idea. I also simplified the way it checks for the last and first posts.

```
var $carousel = $('.post_excerpt_carousel');

$carousel.each(function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    var outer_width = $(window).outerWidth();
    var container_width;

    if (outer_width > 1145) {
        container_width = 1170;
    }

    if (outer_width > 960 && outer_width < 1145) {
        container_width = 960;
    }

    if (outer_width < 960) {
        container_width = parseInt((9/10)*outer_width,10);
    }

    var duration = $this.data('duration');
    var li_number = $this.find('li').length;
    var $ul = $this.find('ul');
    var $li = $ul.find('li');
    $li.removeClass('active');

    if (outer_width < 760){
        $li.css('width', container_width);
        $li.eq(1).addClass('active');
        if ($li.eq(2).hasClass('active')) {
            $li.eq(2).removeClass('active');
        }
    } else if (outer_width > 760){
        $li.eq(1).addClass('active');
        $li.eq(2).addClass('active');
    }

    var list_width = $this.find('li').outerWidth(true);
    var left_offset;

    left_offset = parseInt(list_width - (outer_width - container_width-42)/2, 10);

    $ul.css({'display': 'inline-block', 'width': li_number * $this.find('li').outerWidth(true) + 'px', 'left': -left_offset + 'px'});


    var not_active_no = $this.find('li').not('.first').not('.last').not('.active').length;
    var not_active_width = not_active_no * $this.find('li').outerWidth(true);

    $this.on('click', '.carousel_next', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if($this.find('li.last').prev().hasClass('active')){
            return;
        } else {
            var $a = $('.active', $this);

            if (!$a.next().hasClass('last') && !$ul.is(':animated')) {
                $a.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            }

            if (!$ul.is(':animated')) {
                $ul.animate({
                    left: parseInt($ul.css('left'), 10) - $ul.find('li').outerWidth(true),
                }, duration);
            }
        }

    });

    $this.on('click', '.carousel_prev', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if($this.find('li.first').next().hasClass('active')){
            return;
        } else {
            var $a = $('.active', $this);

            if (!$a.prev().hasClass('first') && !$ul.is(':animated')) {
                $a.removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
            }

            if (!$ul.is(':animated')) {
                $ul.animate({
                    left: parseInt($ul.css('left'), 10) + $ul.find('li').outerWidth(true),
                }, duration);
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Works now as it should :)